# How to customise IBM Mobile First Direct Download Screen?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

What is customisable in IBM Mobile First Direct Download Screen?
(e.g. color to match the theme of the app, wording display...), etc..)

For example: I would like to change the background to red, the loading bar to red, and the "Downloading" word to Updating...

Comment: Reason for downvoting pleae?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would feel the need to include an image which is totally unnecessary. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate a problem. There are a lot of reasons to avoid using images -  while it's specifically about code, [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) explains many of them. Surely anyone who can answer this question would understand what you mean without a large graphic? And those who can't answer it won't benefit from the graphic's presence either.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, sorry for making you uncomfortable and wasting some of your data bandwidth. There are two types of app update in MobileFirst, I just want to make sure I make it clear it's which one. Images are worth a thousand words.

Comment: Images might be worth a thousand words, but they're a waste when a hundred words would suffice. There's no need to filibuster here; more words does not make a good question. :-) It has nothing to do with my discomfort. Apparently you didn't read the linked post, which discusses the vision impaired, corporate proxies, and mobile users who can't see the gigantic image.

Comment: Alright... Image is removed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply update the UI. To be able to customize the second direct update dialog (i.e. the one in the screen shot), this will require you to take control of the [direct update flow entirely](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/#userExprience), which means, you need to be very careful...

[Learn more in the user documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_customizing_direct_update_ui_android_wp8_ios.html)

```
var directUpdateCustomListener = {
  onStart: function(totalSize){
    //show custom progress dialog
  },
  onProgress: function(status,totalSize,completedSize){
    //update custom progress dialog
  },
  onFinish: function(status){

    if (status == 'SUCCESS'){
      //show success message
      WL.Client.reloadApp();
    }
    else {
      //show custom error message

      //submitFailure must be called is case of error
      wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
    }
  }
};

wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext){

  WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Avalible', 'Press update button to download version 2.0', [{
    text : 'update',
    handler : function() {
      directUpdateContext.start(directUpdateCustomListener);
    }
  }]);
};
```